# 38kHz, 50% duty cycle PWM output on GPIO

Tags: python, pwm, node.js

I'd like to generate 38kHz & 50% duty cycle PWM signals on multiple GPIO pins. Hence hardware PWM won't work for me.

Does anyone have a chance to generate this signal by using python or node.js?

Tried python RPI.GPIO library to generate manually, but the maximum frequency seems ~8kHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) waves to generate PWM at 38 kHz on multiple GPIO simultaneously.

You can do this using the pigpio [Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) and there are wrappers for [node.js](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Other_Languages).

There are several relevant examples, e.g.

https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_wavePWM_py

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to use [this](https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio) library to generate waveforms:

```js
const pigpio = require('pigpio');
const Gpio = pigpio.Gpio;

const outPin = 21;

const output = new Gpio(outPin, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
output.digitalWrite(0);

while (true){
  pigpio.waveClear();
  let waveform = [];

  for (let x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    if (x % 2 === 1) {
      waveform.push({ gpioOn: outPin, gpioOff: 0, usDelay: 13 });
    } else {
      waveform.push({ gpioOn: 0, gpioOff: outPin, usDelay: 13 });
    }
  }

  pigpio.waveAddGeneric(waveform);

  let waveId = pigpio.waveCreate();

  if (waveId >= 0) {
    pigpio.waveTxSend(waveId, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT);
  } else {
    break
  }

  try{
    while (pigpio.waveTxBusy()) {}
  }
  catch (err){
    throw err;
  }
  pigpio.waveDelete(waveId);
}
```

NOTE: The problem is that the accuracy of the wave length is 1µs, hence my oscilloscope says that the frequency of the generated signal is 38.45kHz.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that the resolution is 1 µs.  However that is not a problem for IR transmitters or receivers.